# Removing non-breaking spaces from strings using Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, text

I am having some trouble with a very basic string issue in Python (that I can't figure out). Basically, I am trying to do  the following:

```
'# read file into a string 
myString =  file.read()

'# Attempt to remove non breaking spaces 
myString = myString.replace("\u00A0"," ")

'# however, when I print my string to output to console, I get: 
Foo **<C2><A0>** Bar
```

I thought that the "\u00A0" was the escape code for unicode non breaking spaces, but apparently I am not doing this properly. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using (the answer may differ depending on whether you are using 2.x or 3.x)?

Comment: Hi Kathy, yes I am using Python v2.5.1

Comment: Edited my answer in response.

Answer (score 57):

You don't have a unicode string, but a UTF-8 list of bytes (which are what strings are in Python 2.x).

Try

```
myString = myString.replace("\xc2\xa0", " ")
```

Better would be to switch to unicode -- see [this article](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2017/sep/05/how-python-does-unicode/) for ideas.  Thus you could say

```
uniString = unicode(myString, "UTF-8")
uniString = uniString.replace(u"\u00A0", " ")
```

and it should also work (caveat: I don't have Python 2.x available right now), although you will need to translate it back to bytes (binary) when sending it to a file or printing it to a screen.

Comment: Your UTF-8 solution was exactly what I needed to get a non-breaking space into a log file. Though the output looks strange when the logger echoes the log record to the console, which isn't UTF-8, of course, it looks strange, but it becomes completely invisible in the log file, causing it to appear exactly as I needed, with a blank line above my column labels.

Comment: Looks like the site went away.. I'll look for an alternate like.

Comment: Is using `unicode()` function or u"" required in Python 3? I am asking about that because my understanding is Python 3 codes every and any string only in unicode.

Comment: This answer is definitely a 2.x answer -- Python 3 treats strings differently.

Answer (score 12):

I hesitate before adding another answer to an old question, but since Python3 counts a Unicode "non-break space" character as a whitespace character, and since strings are Unicode by default, you can get rid of non-break spaces in a string `s` using `join` and `split`, like this:

```
s = ' '.join(s.split())
```

This will, of course, also change any other white space (tabs, newlines, etc).  You can find a list of Unicode characters that would be changed, in the table in the [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) page on Wikipedia.

And note that this is Python3 only.

Comment: This is not working in 2022.

Comment: In what way is it not working in 2022?  Which version of `python3` did you try?

Comment: @Thruston this approach doesn't work for the following string, `abc999\u202c`. I'm not sure though if `\u202c` is a non-breaking space. Do you have any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: that's because a PDF char = u202c is not whitespace.   See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm. You might like to try https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Comment: @TheConfax use `ord()` func and double check, clearing out UC_160 whitespace works for me!

Answer (score 7):

No, `u"\u00A0"` is the escape code for non-breaking spaces. `"\u00A0"` is 6 characters that are not any sort of escape code. [Read this](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: The link you provided might be good for a beginner but it is misleading. It completely neglects Unicode normalization e.g., `'ć'` is `u'\u0107'` and it could be represented as `u'c\u0301'` http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Answer (score 6):

Please note that a simple `myString.strip()` will remove not only spaces, but also non-breaking-spaces from the beginning and end of myString. Not exactly what the OP asked for, but still very handy in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply solve this issue by enforcing the encoding.

```
 cleaned_string = myString.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 3):

Also note that python's whitespace regex character matches non-breaking spaces.

The following code will replace one-or-more spaces/non-breaking-spaces with a single space

```py
import re

re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', u"String with    spaces and non\u00A0breaking\u00A0spaces")
# 'String with spaces and non breaking spaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication in what you write that you're necessarily doing anything wrong: if the original string had a non-breaking space between 'Foo' and 'Bar', you now have a normal space there instead.  This assumes that at some point you've decoded your input string (which I imagine is a bytestring, unless you're on Python 3 or `file` was opened with the function from the `codecs` module) into a Unicode string, else you're unlikely to locate a unicode character in a non-unicode string of bytes, for the purposes of the `replace`.  But still, there are no clear indications of problems in what you write.

Can you clarify what's the input (print `repr(myString)` just before the replace) and what's the output  (print `repr(myString)` again just *after* the replace) and why you think that's a problem?  Without the `repr`, strings that are actually different might *look* the same, but `repr` helps there.