# Python 3: Reading string from file and define the same string in code working differently

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file, encoding

I have a text file like below

```
    # 1.txt
    who is the\u00a0winners\u00a0where\u00a0season result\u00a0is 7th
```

If I read a file and print it, it shows

```
    >>> s = open("1.txt").read()
    >>> print(s)
    who is the\u00a0winners\u00a0where\u00a0season result\u00a0is 7th
```

However, If I do like below with the same string,

```
    >> s = "who is the\u00a0winners\u00a0where\u00a0season result\u00a0is 7th"
    >> print(s)
    who is the winners where season result is 7th
```

I want to read a text file like "1.txt" and print it like the below one. I can not find how to do it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: `\u....` in *string literals* are being interpreted, read from text files they're not.

Comment: Seems to have been discussed already before.
Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594810/removing-non-breaking-spaces-from-strings-using-python

Comment: @deceze, Thanks for your comment. Is there a way to handle \u... in text file?

Answer (score 0):

`\u00a0` is a non break space and is *one character*.

In your first example your are reading `\u00a0` as 6 chars.

If you want to read a file with `\u00a0`s and interpret them as spaces, you would have to parse the file yourself and create spaces for each `\u00a0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have several more unicodes. \u20132,  \u20136, \u00e4 etc. Should I parse every \u things to read it? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the question in the answer of @Kenstars, one answer to that question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594942/4572356 . It is maybe the easiest way to do what you want to accomplish. Essentially using `.replace` on the string to replace a `\u...` with what it's definition is.